# Soap UI returning HTTP 1.1/200 OK but empty response - works in mendix 7 but not 8

Tags: soap, request, soapui, mendix

I am testing a web service with SOAPUI, using a wsdl with a soap request. The request returns 200 but the response is empty. Also, we are using this service in mendix and it works perfectly well in mendix 7 (with the "old deprecated web service implementation" set in Project Settings/Runtime) but not in mendix 8 (same wsdl, same SOAP request).

see also: https://forum.mendixcloud.com/link/questions/100738

Any help appreciated. Thanks in advance!

[view SOAP UI screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KOFWk.png)

Answer (score 0):

It’s not clear what is causing that issue but there is one possible work around.

If you look at web service in SOAP UI, it internally calls an URL with some headers and body. You can use Rest Service instead of web service in microflow with the same headers and body. You won’t need any wsdl file for this.

Let me know if this works out!!

Answer (score 0):

It all depends on what you map in the response parameter! If the Domain model structure is not proper then it wont show you in mendix.
What you can do is, in the locally running mendix or in server, you can enable Webservice trace logs to see the API call request and response. This will always show what you send and what you are receiving. So from there you can do your debugging.